# Conditions for a (2x2) block matrix to be Positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let us consider a given symmetric matrix
\begin{equation}
M=\begin{bmatrix}0 & B\\
B^{T} & C
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
My question may seem very simple but what conditions must the block
matrices follow in order to make the big matrix positive definite
please? A, B and C are matrices. 
Thanks.

Comment: Not with a zero subblock because $$\begin{bmatrix} v^* & 0 \end{bmatrix}M\begin{bmatrix} v \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = v^*0v = 0.$$ Positive semi-definite is still a possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much T. Gunn: you are right.

Comment: If the (1,1) block is zero, then also $B$ must be zero.

Comment: Thanks Algebraic Pavel. I think finally that M cannot be positive definite since M=0 is not positive definite.

Comment: What about M=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\
B^{T} & 0
\end{bmatrix} then please?

Comment: It's the same thing: $$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & v^* \end{bmatrix} M \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ v \end{bmatrix} = v^*0v = 0. $$ Also you can conjugate by $$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ I & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$ to get back to the first form.

Comment: A matrix with zero(s) on the diagonal can never ever be positive definite. It can only be positive semi-definite and, if $M$ has zeros on the diagonal, that can happen only if for every diagonal zero entry the whole corresponding row and column is zero. That is a consequence of [this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518763/column-space-of-positive-semidefinite-matrix).

Comment: Thank you very much T. Gunn

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful comment Algebraic Pavel

Comment: Also have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2280671/321264.

Comment: Thanks StubbornAtom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm creating an answer from the comments.

---

If $M$ has a zero subblock in the (1,1) position then $M$ cannot be positive definite because
$$ \begin{bmatrix} v^T & 0 \end{bmatrix}M\begin{bmatrix} v \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = v^T0v = 0. $$

Nor can it have a zero subblock in the (2,2) position because then it is conjugate to a matrix with a zero subblock in the (1,1) position:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ I & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ B^{T} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ I & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B^T \\ B & A \end{bmatrix}. $$
You can also see this directly
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & v^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A & B\\ B^{T} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ v \end{bmatrix} = v^T0v = 0. $$

---

If the (1,1) subblock is $0$ and $M$ is positive *semi*definite then the $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ must be zero as a consequence of [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518763). This leaves us with

$$ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & C\end{bmatrix} $$

which is positive semidefinite iff $C$ is positive semidefinite.